# Using Views and Date module in Drupal 7 - Limiting Filter Options

Tags: views, datetime

I am creating an event calendar for a festival where user's can log into the site, click "Add new event" and create an event.  I have 2 questions regarding dates.

1. When the user creates the event, rather than a standard date popup, I'd like for them to be able to choose a range of days (Thursday - Sunday) and a time, rather than the calendar popup or Day/month/year hour minute drop downs.  Is there an easy way to limit this, of even prevent the user from selecting dates outside a certain range?
2. When showing the events list, I've created a table view.  I'd like to allow the user to select which days to display using an exposed filter.  If I choose "Event date" it only allows me to display a standard date field in the filter (Month Day Year).  I want the user to be able to select "All, Thursday, Friday, Saturday or Sunday" instead.  I was able to add "Day" as a field in the view, and group by the DAY, It just seems I'm not able to then filter by it.

I hope this makes some sort of logical sense.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently "date" module doesn't allow to satisfy this needs

I see two solutions for the first question:

1) Develop a custom module in order to create this type of interaction.

2) A quick and dirty alternative is to alter the dropdown content using JS, but a custom module would be miles better.

Sincerely I'll suggest the first one.

About the second question you could expose the day filter and populate it substituting the form filter with a custom one, for example hiding the original form filter with CSS (display:none) and adding some hand crafted links with the URL parameters on the views header area.

Good work!